# Flutter App: Navigating to Blank Page After Tapping Back Button from Push Notification

Tags: android, flutter, navigation, flutter-navigation

i create an app that have push notification in background, when the user tap the notification bubble, it can navigate smoothly to the page. but the problem is when the user tap the back button in the android phone, it will go to the blank page  [image]

here is my code

```
return await CustomDialog.show(
        context,
        title: "Quit App",
        description: "Are you sure you want to quit the app?",
        btnCancelText: "No",
        btnOkText: "Yes",
        btnCancelOnPress: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        btnOkOnPress: () {
         
          Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
        },
        icon: Iconsax.info_circle,
        dialogType: DialogType.success,
      )
```

i try the `SystemNavigator.pop();` but still not working

Answer (score 1):

It's occurs because when you navigate from background you direct load the specific page. It's not the correct way to load the page, you should load your splash/initial page first or your landing page then load your specific page.It will solve your problem. Try to focus on your navigation load.

Answer (score 0):

That is because there seems to be only one page available in your stack. This could be solved by using the correct `Navigator`.

Please add more code to where the routing to the Notification actually occurs.

Comment: ` Navigator.push(
            navigatorKey.currentState!.context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => JobDescriptionsScreen(
                      jobId: jobId,
                    )));`

this is my navigator code

Comment: use ` Navigator.push` if you have another page to fallback to. It could be easier if you added more code to your question.